# Direction to take with Android Graphics

Tags: android, android-animation

I am looking at making a simple game. Without giving out the entire story, I need to draw two pieces of fruit (with arms and legs), who do different movements. They can do a few different actions (less than 5) and they also react to each others actions.

I'd like it to look simple. Very 2D, kids sort of graphics. Maybe shaded, but nice bright happy colours.

Let's say an action is to 'throw ball'. I'd like to see a semi smooth arm action. Smooth if possible.

So, I found a tutorial, which used sprites, and a PNG with 3 different states of a person walking. So, very basic. And I was able to make it walk across the screen, leading each part of the PNG for each state, and iterating through that over and over again, while moving the image.

I got pretty happy with my progress, and would like to base my game on that sort of model - but ... is using sprites, and loading areas of the PNG to make the image move correct? My PNG would be large if I want maybe 20 images just to throw the ball.

But if that's the right way to go, then great! It seems you can go with OpenGL and all that, but that's for 3D graphics right? Using sprites, and a few PNG with images would be OK for perforamnce and all that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenGL is a valid choice for 2D or 3D, you shouldn't have any performance issues.

It will work fine for your game, and would likely be much smoother than trying to use android animations, which are not hardware accelerated on Android 2.x.